# PHP Session Cookie not being sent to server

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am having problems with the buildin session functionality of php.
When I start the session the client recieves the session cookie as it is supposed to. But the cookie never gets send back to the server.
All other cookies get send (checked that multiple times). The host is correct and the path aswell.
The php.ini file seemed correct.
I also tried renaming the session cookie without success!

I want to add that every time I access the site I get another session cookie.
Also when I debugged this I added this line `error_log(print_r($_COOKIE, true));` as the first line  of my code. Still no session cookie.

Here is some code I'm using:

```
  // This function exists so that I only start the session once.
  function start_session() {
    if(session_id() == "") {
      session_start();
      setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime"));
      // The client gets this cookie!
    }
  }

  start_session();
```

`session.cookie_lifetime` in my php.ini is `0`. Might this be the cause?

I have no idea what might causing this.

Comment: show us relevant code

Comment: What do mean by relevant code? I use session_start (client recieves the cookie!). First thing I do is `error_log(print_r($_COOKIE, true));` and the cookie is not present in the list.

Comment: Relavant code is showing us your code so we can see if you're having problems in the code. We can't make a good answer without having look into it

Comment: Then hang on a sec. The code is fairly scattered

Comment: You seem to be mixing up cookies and sessions

Comment: @donald123 Here you go.

Comment: Call this code `error_log(print_r($_SESSION, true));` What you are doing is to start a session with `session_start()`, and set a cookie with the name if the session. Open the devtools and reload the page. n the network tab click on any POST request and than click on the cookies tab. Tell us what you see.

Comment: @Stanimir empty every time. When I call this after I set values the values appear

Comment: `session.cookie_lifetime = 0` means that the session will last as long as the browser session is on. Which means that if you close the browser all the cookies and sessions will be deleted.

Comment: But doesn't `time() + ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime")` mean the expiration date of the cookie is set to now? Meaning the cookie gets deleted immeadeatly. The code is taken from another project. It might be possible that the value of `session.cookie_lifetime` was not `0`. I'm going to check that.

Comment: It's possible. Try with `time() + 3600`

Comment: @Stanimir That was the cause! After setting the value higher it worked again. Thank you. I will post this as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is `time() + ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime")` with `session.cookie_lifetime` being `0`. Meaning the cookie will expire immediately.

Setting the `session.cookie_lifetime` to something like `3600` worked.